# Mean of standard deviation and confidence intervals

Tags: standard-deviation, means

I have 1000 values from which I calculate the mean A and the standard deviation std A and the 95% confidence interval. I have another 1000 values from which I calculate the mean B and the standard deviation std B and the 95% confidence interval.

If I now calculate the mean of A and B, is it valid to calculate the mean of std A and std B (i.e. the means of the standard devaitions) and the mean of the two confidence intervals?

Comment: Here is a way you can test this. Pick two random samples of size say ten (instead of 1000), between zero and one. Calculate the mean and standard deviations of the two examples. Then calculate the mean and standard deviation of the two samples combine and compare.

Comment: What you propose is in general not correct. The reason is that the standard deviation is non-linear. (It is calculated as the square root of the variance, which is a sum over squared input values.) One can not take the mean of two non-linear values, expecting that it results in the correct value.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to put all 2000 values into one bucket and then calculate from it the mean and the standard deviation?